# Save data via jQuery with web service

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-services

EDIT: Please refer to my website: [www.fredm.co.za](http://www.fredm.co.za), and click on Sign Up, you will see the error message returned.

I am trying to use jQuery to access a Web Service which will add a user to a database.
This is what I have tried:

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#btnSignUp').click(function()
        {
            try
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Some_Web_Service.asmx",
                    data: '{EmailAddress: "fred", FirstName: "fred", Surname: "mol", Birthday: "1991/11/25", Password: "1346", Question: "What?", Answer: "Yes"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: OnFailure
                });
            }
            catch(ex)
            {
                OnFailure(ex.message)
            }
        });
    });

    function OnSuccess(response)
    {
        alert(response.d);
    }

    function OnFailure(response)
    {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

This is my Web Service(Some_Web_Servive.asmx):

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public bool JQuerySignUp(string EmailAddress, string FirstName, string Surname, string Birthday, string Password, string Question, string Answer)
        {
            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("INSERT INTO tblJQueryFredMUsers");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("(");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    EmailAddress,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    FirstName,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    Surname,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    Birthday,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    Passwrd,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    Question,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    Answer");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine(")");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("VALUES");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("(");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    @EmailAddress,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    @FirstName,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    @Surname,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    @Birthday,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    @Passwrd,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    @Question,");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine("    @Answer");
                _stringBuilder.AppendLine(")");

                _params = new List<SqlParameter>();
                _params.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", EmailAddress));
                _params.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", FirstName));
                _params.Add(new SqlParameter("@Surname", Surname));
                _params.Add(new SqlParameter("@Birthday", Birthday));
                _params.Add(new SqlParameter("@Passwrd", Password));
                _params.Add(new SqlParameter("@Question", Question));
                _params.Add(new SqlParameter("@Answer", Answer));

                throw new ArgumentException("asdadada");

                ExecuteQuery(_stringBuilder.ToString(), _params);
                success = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                SendEmailErrorMessage(ex.Message);
                //TODO: Log the details somewhere so that we can look at it later.
                //throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseDatabase();
            }
            return success;
        }
```

So when I publish it on my website's root folder, and go online and access my webspace, I see this:
[image]

If I click there, this opens:
[image]

When I fill this out, is saves to the database
But on my website, when I click the button, nothing happens.
Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: Several questions: Do you get an error returned?  If you remove the quotes around your `data` parameter (just use an object literal instead of a JSON-like string) does that make a difference?  Are you dynamically adding the button to the page, or is it already there by the time the `click` handler is wired up?

Comment: @David Hoerster - No, I dont get any error returned whatsoever. I've also tried removing the quotes, but it still does absolutely nothing. The button is on the page. when you click the button, it executes that code.